# trying to add value into a checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi guys i'm trying to get the compiler to get the information the checkbox checked from the database but couldn't do it how can i add value into the checkbox exactly ! please check attempt of doing so , i need your help guys thanks ..

```
  string query = "SELECT count (1) FROM Login WHERE Username=@Username AND password=@password AND usertype=@usertype";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype",checkbox1);/// how can i add values into checkbox !
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", checkbox2);
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (count == 1)
            {
                if ((bool)checkbox1.IsChecked == true)
                {

                    MainWindow Dashboard = new MainWindow();
                    Dashboard.Show();
                    MessageBox.Show("You'r logged in as an Admin");
                    this.Close();
                }

                if ((bool)checkbox2.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    ;
                    Student stu = new Student();
                    stu.Show();
                    MessageBox.Show("You'r logged in as a Student");
                    this.Close();
            }
```

Comment: What value are you trying to set `@usertype` to?

Comment: Ceckbox1 and ceckbox2 which admin and student @mm8

Comment: @leo your question is not clear, is `@usertype` and integer

Comment: Please add wpf code... If I recall you only need to add `checked>` to it

Comment: @leo: Did you set the `Content` of the `CheckBox` to "admin" or how to you identify them?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i'm trying to tell the system to take the authentication from the database if checkbox1 is checked only admins are allowed to access it hope this clear my question

Comment: @mm8 yse ! Checkbox1 = admin and checkbox2 = student

Comment: @leo: But how do you know that? Did you see my answer? You could just check whether a particular `CheckBox` is checked and then set the parameter accordingly.

Comment: @Missilexent <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox1" Content="admin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox2" Content="student" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="219,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check whether a `CheckBox` is checked and then set the value of the parameter, for example to the `Content` of the checked `CheckBox`:

```
if (checkbox1.IsChecked == true)
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", checkbox1.Content.ToString());
else if (checkbox2.IsChecked == true)
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", checkbox2.Content.ToString());
```

But if you require the `@usertype` parameter to be set, you should use radio buttons rather than check boxes.